# ¿Cómo integrar Volley en el patrón MVVM para sincronizar periódicamente mi base de datos remota con mi base de datos local?

Tags: android, android-volley, mvvm

Estoy tratando de implementar correctamente el patrón MVVM en mi aplicación.

Lo que quiero hacer es una sincronización periódica de una base de datos local en el dispositivo con una base de datos remota.

Las herramientas para lograrlo serían las siguientes:

- Usar `PeriodicWorkRequest` para una sincronización periódica cada X tiempo
- Usar `RequestFuture` de `Volley` para obtener los datos remotos.

No tengo ninguna experiencia usando el patrón MVVM y por más que he leído varios tutoriales no logro ensamblar mi código.

Lo que quiero lograr es algo exactamente parecido a lo explicado en [este respositorio](https://github.com/Ikhiloya/WorkManagerPeriodicRequest/tree/3b0ae3e0a9bbacbcfdf2486368492df0b64b1f0c/app/src/main/java/com/ikhiloyaimokhai/workmanagersyncremotedata), pero en ese código se usa `Retrofit`, y me pierdo sobre todo en la parte de `service` y en la forma de lanzar/integrar/enlazar la respuesta de Volley en un patrón MVVM.

He buscado tutoriales sobre el tema y no he encontrado ninguno. Tengo mucho código escrito, pero no logro que funcione. Como comenté antes, no sé exactamente cómo enlazar los elementos de la forma correcta y esa es mi principal duda: ¿cómo integrar Volley en el patrón MVVM para sincronizar periódicamente mi base de datos remota con mi base de datos local?

El punto principal en el cual estoy perdido es aquí:

En la clase `SyncDataWorker` que será la encargada de lanzar el trabajo:

- se crea una instancia de la clase `BookService` mediante: `bookService = App.get().getBookService();`
- y luego en el método `doWork()` se hace esto:

  ```
   try {
       //create a call to network
       Call<List<Book>> call = bookService.fetchBooks();
       Response<List<Book>> response = call.execute();

       if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null && !response.body().isEmpty() && response.body().size() > 0) {
  ```

La parte del `try` es evidentemente el código `Retrofit` para lanzar la petición a los datos remotos **y no sé cómo integrar `Volley` ahí**.

`BookService` es una interfaz con este código:

```
public interface BookService {

    @GET("getBooks")
    LiveData<ApiResponse<List<Book>>> getBooks();


    @GET("getBooks")
    Call<List<Book>> fetchBooks();
}
```

Es código `Retrofit`, y no sé cómo integrar eso en Volley (o si tiene que ser así o de otro modo).

Luego, en la clase `RemoteSyncViewModel` hay un método `fetchData()` que sería el encargado de programar el `PeriodicWorkRequest`:

```
public void fetchData() {

    // Create Network constraint
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();


    PeriodicWorkRequest periodicSyncDataWork =
            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(SyncDataWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .addTag(TAG_SYNC_DATA)
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    // setting a backoff on case the work needs to retry
                    .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();
    mWorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            SYNC_DATA_WORK_NAME,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, //Existing Periodic Work policy
            periodicSyncDataWork //work request
    );

}
```

Ese método es invocado desde `MainActivity`:

```
mRemoteSyncViewModel.fetchData();
```

Y realmente entre Vista, Model, Repository, LiveData y otras historias me pierdo y no logro entender cómo queda ensamblado todo esto ni cómo podría traducirlo a `Volley`.

Comment: Tal y como planteas la pregunta, estás buscando un ejemplo. Y ese tipo de preguntas está sujeto a opiniones y no están permitidas.

Comment: @Juanjo, entiendo tu punto. Sin embargo no sé cómo afrontar el problema y por eso he abierto la pregunta. He buscado en inglés y en castellano y no encuentro nada que me oriente.

Comment: Aunque la pregunta apunta a buscar opiniones, tiene mi +1, porque es suficientemente interesante; y, se pone en el ojo del huracán: con el auge de las aplicaciones móviles interactuando con servidores es un problema que tarde o temprano vamos a tener que enfrentar los que trabajamos en soluciones de software para el "mundo real"

Comment: Volley hace peticiones a un backend, por lo que debe inyectarse en un datasource y el repositorio hace lógica de acceso a datos (flujos), por ejemplo, pilla datos de local, si no tengo entonces ve a la api, guárdalos en local y ahora pide datos de local y devolver lo guardado. Una vez el datasource recibe el dato de la api, el repo lo recibe y es en ese momento cuando se actualiza el livedata con tu resultado.  El livedata es observado por el ViewModel y actualizará la UI. (Haciendo modelos de datos y sus mappers entre capas).

Comment: Puedes echar un vistazo a este artículo de medium dónde explican cómo implementar una arquitectura limpia en Android además del enlace al repositorio.   La arquitectura de Google no lo es porque no usa capa de Dominio, pero es una arquitectura válida para ciertos proyectos.  https://medium.com/puntotech/c%C3%B3mo-implementar-una-arquitectura-limpia-en-android-59b7510cef3

Comment: @ManuelMato gracias por tus comentarios, cuando pueda revisaré el enlace. Aunque esto no lo entendí: *La arquitectura de Google no lo es porque no usa capa de Dominio*, o, ¿donde dice *Google* quiste decir *Volley*?

Comment: En el libro de Clean Architecture se mencionan las capas que debe tener una arquitectura limpia y ésto incluye una capa dónde se realiza lógica de la aplicación y negocio: Capa de Dominio con Use Cases y Entities.  En la arquitectura de Google no existe la capa de Dominio, por lo que si hay que hacer lógica de negocio, irá en el Repositorio (cuando la responsabilidad del repositorio no es hacer lógica de negocio, sino de acceso a datos)